# Trane BLU068-A1 Furnace not heating

Tags: furnace, central-heating

I have a Trane BLU068-A1 furnace that will not "heat" (the fan will run) on its own. I "can" get the furnace to heat by using a long bbq lighter and lighting the pilot light directly. This only runs the furnace for 5 minutes or so. I have to re-light it before the fan quits for the heat to continue. I can hear the "relay" click, as if it wants to re-ignite, but it doesn't (seem to) light the pilot flame.

This started with a thermostat that went bad (battery leak corroded the PCB--at least that is what I noticed upon inspection). I changed it with a programmable one, but the furnace would only hold temperature/run intermittently (erratically). I just changed that out back to a non-programmable unit to just get the heater to hold a temperature, thinking that the programmable one was defective. Didn't change the problem--now, it just won't heat (unless I force it to).

A couple thoughts in debugging. A comment was made elsewhere about the ignition module (CNT01704) possibly being defective, but never conclusively proven so. It would make sense, even if the furnace was heating (erratically) with the programmable thermostat, meaning there may be an intermittent short on the IM PCB somewhere (due to a voltage spike). I also noticed a little buildup on what I think is the temperature sensor, but I think this less likely to be the cause, but can't rule it out. As for other parts, I just don't know.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Clean the pilot flame sensor, if that is not reading correctly, because of dirt, the furnace will not work.  Work from simple to hard stuff.

Comment: Cleaned off both sensors with scotch bright. Still won't ignite the pilot light, unless I use the lighter method.